# how to resolve tensorflow gradient issue with large weight matrix dimension?

Tags: tensorflow

I am trying to compute gradient using tf.gradient by passing loss and update the weight using the gradient. I observe that the gradients are zero when the weight matrix dimension is large. What could be the reason for this?

I see that there is no error in the code. I  am getting non-zero gradients with smaller weight matrix and input vector sizes. typically for input vector size of 1*100 and weight of 100x50 the FP value will be 1 x 50. and during BP ip will be 1 x 50 and weight will be 50 x 100. BP vector will be 1 x 100.

loss is sum of differences of Forward (FP) and Backward propagation (BP) values. FP values are input vector (IP) - sigmoid(IP x weight) and BP values - sigmoid(FP x weight.Transpose).

```
var_grad = tf.gradients(loss, [weight_matrix])[0]
update = tf.subtract(weight_matrix,(tf.mul(var_grad,0.1)))
```

I am calling the TF graph as below

```
result,cost,gradient = sess.run([update,loss,var_grad], feed_dict={weight_matrix: weight_mat})
```

Forward propagation values

```
w = tf.matmul(final,weight)
sig = tf.sigmoid(w)
```

loss is computed as

```
for i in range(len(PopulatedList)):
    branch = PopulatedList[i]

    RC_FP = branch['RC_FP']
    RC_BP = branch['RC_BP']
    LC_FP = branch['RC_FP']
    LC_BP = branch['LC_BP']
    loss = tf.reduce_sum(tf.squared_difference(RC_FP_TF,RC_BP_TF),[0, 1]) + tf.reduce_sum(tf.squared_difference(LC_FP_TF,LC_BP_TF),[0, 1])

    out_error.append(loss)

error = tf.reduce_sum(out_error)
return error
```

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing seemingly wrong in your code, so what you're seeing is probably a consequence of how you initialize your weights.